# jQuery Mobile Collapsible set, How to check which collapsible element is expanded?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a dynamically created collapsible set. I need to find out which element is expanded in the collapsible set.

If it is list, we can obtain the clicked list element something like this,

```
$('ul').children('li').on('click', function () {
                 name = $.trim($(this).text());
});
```

How can I do it for collapsible set?.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`expand` and `collapse` events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-events.html)** on `collapsible`s that constitute a `collapsible-set`

```js
$(document).on("expand", "div[data-role=collapsible-set] div[data-role=collapsible]", function(){
    var title = $(this).find(".ui-btn-text")
                       .contents()
                       .filter(function(){
                           return this.nodeType == 3;
                       }).text();
    alert("Expanded: " + title);
});

$(document).on("collapse", "div[data-role=collapsible-set] div[data-role=collapsible]", function(){
    // your code goes here
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yrr45/1/)**

Comment: thanks for the answer. but peterm we are getting some text saying "click to collapse". where it is coming from and cant we avoid it?.

Comment: @user2143817 You're welcome. It's because there is a nested `span` with this message. See updated answer on how to get rid of it.

Comment: I have a small doubt. In my collapsible element i have the count bubble also. is their any way i can get the value of count bubble also?.

Comment: @user2143817 Please consider to post it as another question since it doesn't directly connected to your original question. Make sure to post html markup you use to define collapsible with bubbles. Then other members of community or I will be more than happy to help you.

Comment: thanks peterm, i have added as a new question and here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578287/getting-the-count-bubble-value-upon-clicking-on-collapsible-set